No service for type HttpLogger has been registered in .NET 6
This is the class that I am trying to use with my refit client as a logger, but I am getting an error when registering the dependency of it as a scoped :
public class HttpLogger : IHttpClientLogger
{
    private readonly ILogger<HttpLogger> _logger;

    public HttpLogger(ILogger<HttpLogger> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public object? LogRequestStart(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Sending '{Request.Method}' to '{Request.Host}{Request.Path}'",
            request.Method,
            request.RequestUri?.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped),
            request.RequestUri!.PathAndQuery);
        return null;
    }

    public void LogRequestStop(
        object? context, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response, TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Received '{Response.StatusCodeInt} {Response.StatusCodeString}' after {Response.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms",
            (int)response.StatusCode,
            response.StatusCode,
            elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F1"));
    }

    public void LogRequestFailed(
        object? context,
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpResponseMessage? response,
        Exception exception,
        TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        _logger.LogError(
            exception,
            "Request towards '{Request.Host}{Request.Path}' failed after {Response.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms",
            request.RequestUri?.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped),
            request.RequestUri!.PathAndQuery,
            elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F1"));
    }
}

I have tried to register like this but it is still giving same error :
services.AddScoped<IHttpClientLogger, HttpLogger>();

services.AddScoped<HttpLogger>();

This is how I am using it :
return services
    .AddRefitClient<TService>(refitSettings)
    .AddLogger<HttpLogger>(wrapHandlersPipeline: true);

What am I missing here?

Where are you registering the event?   It may have to do with it being private : private readonly ILogger _logger;

Please update your question and add the complete error and its details to your question.
